# Joomla in PhpStorm mysql tables prefix not valid

Tags: joomla, phpstorm

I have PhpStorm and Joomla project. The names of tables in the database are not substituted from the database, since PhpStorm does not correctly substitute the prefix from the configuration file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks similar for me: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-48688

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved by JetBrains Support.

It is necessary that:

1. The configuration file was located in the Joomla directory
2. That the catalog from Joomla was added to the External Libraries in Project's panel (left screen).